# How to change the background color of the “more” item in ActionMode?

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar

The "more" item will show on the `ActionMode` when there are more than 3 items, but it is automatically generated. I want change the background when I press it. What should I do?
I'm working on Android 4.0 API level 15.

[image: more item]

Comment: I have changed the ActionMode background by:
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionmode_translucent</item>
The "more" item will show noting when I press it.How to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

```
<style name="Theme.Seven" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    ...
    ...
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/action_background</item>
</style>
```

action_background.xml as below:

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dismiss_pressed" />
 <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>`